# Can I use Sir William Brinton's ability immediately after discovering I have to lose Stamina?

Tags: arkham-horror

The Ally Sir William Brinton say

> Discard to immediately restore your Stamina to its maximum.

Can I choose to do this after I've learned I need to lose Stamina, but before I actually deduct that stamina? While the card lets me immediately restore Stamina, it sounds like it shouldn't be used to interrupt something that seems to happen immediately. For instance if a location card I read says "Lose 2 stamina" I would think you cannot use Brinton to heal first, then apply the loss. If it says to do a Fight check and lose 2 stamina if I fail, I would think the same restriction holds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use powers like that before drawing the encounter, or after resolving it (if you are not yet unconscious/insane), but you cannot use it during the resolution of an encounter.

From the [Arkham Horror FAQ](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/9b/2a/9b2a9f8f-0b42-45ba-bcd2-87dc55c68f5f/complete_arkham_horror_faq.pdf) (page 14):

> **Q:** When can a character perform actions during a phase?
>   For example, if a player with the ally Duke (“discard to
>   immediately restore your Sanity to its maximum”) draws
>   an encounter and has to roll a die and lose that much
>   Sanity, when can he discard Duke to restore Sanity: not at
>   all once the encounter card is drawn, before the roll, or
>   after the roll?
>
> **A:** He may discard Duke after the roll, provided he
>   has not been driven insane. Actions can be performed
>   at any time during their listed phase as long as any given
>   conditions are met. However, once an encounter is drawn,
>   it must be resolved before any more actions can be performed.
>   So, in the case of Duke, you can use him before
>   or after drawing an encounter card, but if you draw the
>   encounter card and it inflicts Sanity loss that reduces you
>   to 0 Sanity, you go insane before you can use Duke. Flesh
>   Ward is one exception to this rule because it prevents a
>   Stamina loss and is intended to be used in response to such
>   events. The Premonition Spell [CotDP] is another exception.

Comment: What if the encounter involves a monster appearing? Can he use it somewhere in the middle of that fight as he proceeds to take actions that progressively could result in Stamina loss? It seems he should be able to use it anytime in a fight (except for right after a skill check and before the results incur damage), but that fight could be within the bounds of an encounter card.

Comment: Yeah I am not sure about that situation, and it is not specifically covered by the FAQ as far as I can see. On the one hand, the encounter is technically not resolved until after the combat finishes. But on the other hand, items like this should be usable between the separate steps of combat. The way I would handle it on a technical level is that you can use the items during an encounter, but they cannot interrupt an event eg. taking damage from the encounter, resolving a single combat round of the encounter etc.